# Openstack installer Autopilot failing at juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have a MAAS node already deployed using juju bootstrap --upgrade tools option and when I run `sudo openstack-install` and select option Autopilot. It appears it is timing out for `entropy.ubuntu.com`. My proxy and DNS is all setup and I can wget and nslookup from MAAS server as below:

```
aavam@maas:~$ wget https://streams.canonical.com
--2016-05-03 10:22:26--  https://streams.canonical.com/
Connecting to 64.102.255.47:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 948 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.3’  

100%[================================================================================================================================================>] 948         --.-K/s   in 0s  
2016-05-03 10:22:27 (33.7 MB/s) - ‘index.html.3’ saved [948/948]  

aavam@maas:~$ wget https://entropy.ubuntu.com
--2016-05-03 10:22:41--  https://entropy.ubuntu.com/
Connecting to 64.102.255.47:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2016-05-03 10:22:42 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

aavam@maas:~$ wget https://91.189.94.24
--2016-05-03 10:23:26--  https://91.189.94.24/
Connecting to 64.102.255.47:80... connected.
    ERROR: certificate common name ‘entropy.ubuntu.com’ doesn't match requested host name ‘91.189.94.24’.
To connect to 91.189.94.24 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

aavam@maas:~$ wget --no-check-certificate https://91.189.94.24
--2016-05-03 10:23:47--  https://91.189.94.24/
Connecting to 64.102.255.47:80... connected.
    WARNING: certificate common name ‘entropy.ubuntu.com’ doesn't match requested host name ‘91.189.94.24’.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2016-05-03 10:23:48 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

aavam@maas:~$ nslookup 91.189.94.24
Server:         172.55.122.165
Address:        172.55.122.165#53

Non-authoritative answer:
24.94.189.91.in-addr.arpa       name = okra.canonical.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
94.189.91.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns3.canonical.com.
94.189.91.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns1.canonical.com.
94.189.91.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns2.canonical.com.
ns1.canonical.com       internet address = 91.189.94.173
ns2.canonical.com       internet address = 91.189.95.3
ns3.canonical.com       internet address = 91.189.91.139
```

[image]

Comment: does sudo openstack-install spins another shell and some how not getting the env from its native shell.......ie where it is spinning from......

Comment: what interface can i tcpdump for this install for more clues.... currently i am setup on MAAS eth1 (10x.x.x.x)....juju-br0 (10.x.x.x) interface on the MAAS deployed node after juju bootstrap .....  Also any logs to tail...... I am not seeing commands.log under cloud_install directory....